# Next-auth middleware 'eval' not allowed

Tags: authentication, next.js, middleware, next-auth

I'm trying to implement a simple next-auth middleware to protect all api routes except a `/api/healthcheck` route.

I wrote the following within `/pages/api/_middleware`

```
import { withAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware';

// protect all api routes but /api/healthcheck
export default withAuth({
  callbacks: {
    authorized: async ({ req, token }) => {
      if (req.page.name === '/api/healthcheck') return true;
      if (token) return true;
      return false;
    },
  },
});
```

This seems to work correctly on localhost but when I try to build I get the following error

```
Dynamic Code Evaluation (e. g. 'eval', 'new Function') not allowed in Middleware pages/api/_middleware
```

Any ideas what can cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I mistaken made the authorized callback `async` which apparently is forbidden